# String could not be resolved c++

Tags: c++, string

I am wondering why I am getting `error "string could not be resolved to type"` when I have the proper inclusions?

```
#ifndef EVENTFILEREADER_H_
#define EVENTFILEREADER_H_
#include <string>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <iostream>

class EventFileReader {
public:
    EventFileReader(string fileName);
    virtual ~EventFileReader();
};

#endif /* EVENTFILEREADER_H_ */
```

Comment: Because it's called `std::string`.

Answer (score 2):

Your compiler is complaining about not being able to find `string` as a defined type.

You should add its namespace `std`:

```
EventFileReader(std::string fileName);
                ^^^^^
```

Comment: Indeed, it's because the "string" class is in the "std" namespace, but your code is not. By default, the compiler will not search other namespaces. So you you must either explicitly specify the namespace or implicitly include using the "using namespace" keyword.

Comment: do not `using namespace std` inside a header. It's a disaster!

Answer (score 1):

You need to specify namespace, e.g.

```
std::string
```

or put the using declaration after includes:

```
using std::string;
```

Comment: using `std::string` can also be troublesome, but it's sure waaay better thans using whole namespace.

Comment: Never put `using` declarations in headers.